# iOS Pin color issue in mapkit

Tags: ios, mkannotation, apple-maps

I want my annotations in two colors. For that I have used following code,

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {  
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlaceMark class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        @try {
            if (annotationView == nil) {
                annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                  initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                  reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            } else {
                annotationView.annotation = annotation;
                
                if([[nsCenterOrOffice objectAtIndex:z] isEqualToString:@"C"])
                {
                    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
                }
                else 
                {
                    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"nsCenterOrOffice exception = %@",exception);
        }
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

But still I am not able to set desired color for desired annotation. Sometimes particular annotation pin color is red and sometimes it's green. I am not getting why this is happening. Can anybody help me ? Thanks...

I rework on my code..this is my updated code

MapAnnotation.h

```
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface MapAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation
    {
        NSString *title;
        NSString *subtitle;
        int dealLnk;
        float latitude;
        float longitude;
        
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) int dealLnk;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) float latitude;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) float longitude;
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

    - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl subTitle:(NSString *)subttl dealLink:(int)dealLnk latitude:(float)latitude longitude:(float)longitude andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;
@end
```

MapAnnotation.m

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation

@synthesize title,subtitle,dealLnk,coordinate,latitude,longitude;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl subTitle:(NSString *)subttl dealLink:(int)z latitude:(float)latitude1 longitude:(float)longitude1 andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    title = ttl;
    subtitle = subttl;
    dealLnk =z;
    coordinate = c2d;
    longitude = longitude1;
    latitude = latitude1;
    
    return self;
}
@end
```

And this is my implementation file

```
-(void)startAddingAnnotation
{
    @try {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
        
        z=0;
        for (int i=0; i < [nslatitude count] ; i++,z++)
        {
            
            MapAnnotation  *dealAnnotation   = [[MapAnnotation  alloc] init];
            
            dealAnnotation.dealLnk = z;
            annotationCoord.latitude =  (CGFloat) [[nslatitude objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
            annotationCoord.longitude = (CGFloat)[[nslongitude objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
            dealAnnotation.coordinate = annotationCoord;
            
            dealAnnotation.title = [nsCenterName objectAtIndex:i];
            dealAnnotation.subtitle = [nsCenterAddress objectAtIndex:i];
            
            NSLog(@"latitude = %f",dealAnnotation.latitude);
            NSLog(@"longitude = %f",dealAnnotation.longitude);
            
            NSLog(@"dealAnnotation.dealLnk = %d",dealAnnotation.dealLnk);
            NSLog(@"dz = %d",z);
            [mapView addAnnotation:dealAnnotation];
           
        }
        
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        
        NSLog(@"Exception = %@",exception);
    }
    
    cord.longitude = -112.05186;
    cord.latitude = 33.46577;
    
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = cord;
    
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta = 1.0, .longitudeDelta = 1.0};
    region.span = span;
    
    [mapView setRegion:region];
    
    
}

#pragma mark - MapView_Delegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    

    MapAnnotation *annotation1 = (MapAnnotation *)annotation;
    z = annotation1.dealLnk;
    
      NSLog(@"annotation1.longitude = %f",annotation1.latitude);
      NSLog(@"annotation1.longitude = %f",annotation1.longitude);
    
    if(z<[nslatitude count])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"pin1";
        
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        
      
        if ( pinView == nil )
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                       initWithAnnotation:annotation1 reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        
        @try {
            
            if([[nsCenterOrOffice objectAtIndex:z] isEqualToString:@"C"])
            {
                pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag1.png"];
            }
            else
            {
                pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag2.png"];
            }
            pinView.annotation = annotation1;
            pinView.tag = [[nsCenterName objectAtIndex:z] intValue];
            
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"nsCenterOrOffice exception = %@",exception);
        }
        
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [pinView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];

        return pinView;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
    
}
```

Now the problem is, all the annotations are pointing some different location. I am not getting why this is happening? Is der anything wrong in my code?

Comment: did you check your condition **[[nsCenterOrOffice objectAtIndex:z] isEqualToString:@"C"]** is satisfied or not?

Comment: yes..that condition is working. No issue in that statement.

Comment: then you can use image for pin

Comment: One issue with the updated code is MapAnnotation is a subclass of MKPointAnnotation and then re-declares coordinate as readonly.  When the code later does `dealAnnotation.coordinate`, this assign is done to a different backing variable than the one that the getter for the new readonly coordinate will read.  As a result, all annotations are probably going to 0,0.  Generally, custom annotation classes should just be a subclass of NSObject and implement the MKAnnotation _protocol_ (eg. `MapAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>`).  And instead of declaring coordinate as `readonly`, use `assign`.

Answer (score 1):

The condition that determines the pin color is based on data *outside* of this delegate method and there is no guarantee that it will be in sync with when this delegate method is called for a particular annotation.

In this `if` condition:

```
if([[nsCenterOrOffice objectAtIndex:z] isEqualToString:@"C"])
```

the `z` variable is apparently some instance variable declared and set (probably right before adding an annotation) outside this delegate method.

Again, there is *no guarantee* that the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method will be called immediately after an annotation is added.  There is also no guarantee that the delegate method will be called only once for each annotation.  **So it's possible that the `z` value does not correspond to the *current* `annotation` that the delegate method is being called for.**

It is very possible for the delegate method to be called well after `addAnnotation` is called, that it will be called in a different order than the annotations were added, and that it will be called multiple times for each annotation (eg. if user pans or zooms the map and annotations come back into view).

To fix this, add the "is center or office" property to the `Placemark` class itself and set that property when creating the annotation and *before* calling `addAnnotation`.  Then, in the `viewForAnnotation` method, you can cast the `annotation` parameter as a `Placemark` and access the property to implement the condition.  For example:

```
//where you create and add the annotation:
Placemark *pm = [[Placemark alloc...
pm.coordinate = ...
pm.title = ...
pm.centerOrOffice = [nsCenterOrOffice objectAtIndex:z];
[mapView addAnnotation:pm];


//in viewForAnnotation:
Placemark *myPlacemark = (Placemark *)annotation;
if ([myPlacemark.centerOrOffice isEqualToString:@"C"])
...
```

A separate, unrelated issue is that the annotation view creation logic is not quite right.
The code calls `initWithAnnotation` twice and in actuality the second `initWithAnnotation` never gets called since the first call will always succeed.

What you probably wanted was to first call `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` and then, if that returns `nil`, call `initWithAnnotation`.

When restructuring the code in `viewForAnnotation`, be sure to put the code that sets the `pinColor` *outside* the dequeue/init of the annotation view (eg. right before the `return annotationView;`) to properly handle reused views.

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewForAnnotation` is relying upon some external variables, `nsCenterOrOffice` and `z`. We certainly can't help you until you show us how you're setting those variables.

Regardless, this is not a prudent practice. Your `viewForAnnotation` generally should rely solely upon properties of the `annotation`, not external variables.

Comment: @user2260521 That revised `viewForAnnotation` looks more promising. There are a ton of issues here, of varying degrees of significance (the only obvious bug is `initWithTitle` doesn't call `[super init]`, but then again, you don't use this method, so that's unlikely to be the source of your problem). If your problem is that the annotation is added right, but simply the wrong icon, you should log `[nsCenterOrOffice objectAtIndex:z]` in your `viewForAnnotation`. If your problem is something else, please clarify what the current problem is.